# WienerProcess - estimate the expected value after `n` steps

Tags: stochastic-calculus, random-process

Is there a way to adjust the estimated value of the WienerProcess after `n` steps?

Eg. could we evaluate the value of

```
data = RandomFunction[WienerProcess[.3, .5], {0, 1, 0.01}]
```

after `n` steps?

The sample code is from the documentation and I could not find the example that would answer my question.

Comment: [From the documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WienerProcess.html): The state at time $t$ follows `NormalDistribution[μ*t,σ*√t]`.

Comment: Thanks @Roman! So `t` is a step, yes?

Comment: There are no "steps" in the Wiener process. It's a continuous process. $t$ is the variable describing the continuous process; usually $t$ is time.

Answer (score 1):

The parameter you specify: 0.3 and 0.5 are actually the mean and the standard deviation (STD) at t==1.

You can get the mean and STD directly from the definition. E.g. at t==1:

```
Mean[WienerProcess[.3, .5][1]]
(* 0.3 *)
StandardDeviation[WienerProcess[.3, .5][1]]
(* 0.5 *)
```

And at t==2:

```
Mean[WienerProcess[.3, .5][2]]
(* 0.6 *)
StandardDeviation[WienerProcess[.3, .5][2]]
(* 0.707107 *)
```

Comment: So would this `RandomFunction[
 WienerProcess[
  Mean[WienerProcess[.3, .5][
    StandardDeviation[WienerProcess[.3, .5][2500]]]], sd], {0, 1, 
  0.01}]` mean I get a random Weiner walk adjusted for 2500steps? Would `t` == 1000 mean 1000steps? What is a step really? This is a new area to me so sorry for rudimentay questions.

Comment: Your syntax for WienerProcess is wrong. Look it up in the help.  I think the help answers your questions.